# How can I change td background color depending on value in a table using JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am inserting append data dynamically into a product table. There are some td column. Now I want to change background color depending on available product using JavaScript/jQuery.

Appending data into table like this:

```
function getProductData(name, code, rate, available) {
    $('#test tr:last').after("<tr><td><input value='" + name + "'></td><td><input value='" + Code + "'></td><td><input value='" + rate + "'></td><td><input id='available_" + id + "' value='" + available + "' ></td></tr>");
}
```

Here is my table:

```
<tbody id="test">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Table is showing all data perfectly. Now I need to change background color for for the available column depending on their values : like :: `if available > 0 then green color < 0 then red color`.

Please me out. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: define available in your context.?

Comment: Now it is working PERFECTLY @ Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$('#test [id^="available_"]').each(function(){

   var closestTd = $(this).closest('td');
   var valueCache = parseInt($(this).val());

   if(valueCache > 0) {
      closestTd .addClass('positive');
   }
   else if(valueCache < 0) {
      closestTd.addClass('negative');
   }
   else {
      //Apply any color as per your wish for value = 0;
   }

});
```

And define css rules for that classes,

```
.positive{  background-color : green; } 
.negative{  background-color : red; }
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oops sorry, just felt interested with the concept he asked. :)

Comment: Fair enough. :-) Bug report: You're assigning the color red when the value is 0. The assignment -- er, I mean, question -- only used red for values *less than* zero.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :D ...great catch.. Is it fair enough now.?

Comment: Read this bit again: "if available > 0 then green color < 0 then red color" :-) Good to use classes; I'd probably give them names like `positive` and `negative` (e.g., functional names rather than color names).

Comment: Apologies for inconvenience. I just asked this question as short. It is not working by the way @ Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy. Would you please like to check it again ?

Comment: @selim Can you make a working demo of your code.? so that we could fix your issues easily.?

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy. I have earlier demo. I am testing on it. Please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/selimppc/ZU5EK/

Comment: @selim You have some bugs with your css, Try this http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/ZU5EK/1/

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy. I am really really sorry for inconvenience. It is working PERFECTLY. Thank you so MUCH.